# How do we mock an azure end point?

Tags: ios, azure, proxy, charles-proxy, azure-api-management

I am working with an azure API endpoint.  `....azure-api.net/...`.  When I try to view a HTTP request  / response using Charles proxy, the HTTP response is empty. The request works when I turn the proxy off.

I want to intercept the requests and mock the response for the purposes of automation tests.

I can view other HTTPs end-points to other servers using Charles proxy.  So I believe there is something special about azure that is preventing the request from completing.

- How does azure know there is a proxy in the middle and it is not talking to the client?
- Is there anyway to configure the azure API to allow Charles to work? (Since viewing HTTP traffic is useful for development)
- Is there another method that will allow the traffic to azure to be mocked?  E.g. host redirect?

I am using standard iOS networking code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://MyDomain.azure-api.net/a/b/2?subscription-key=myKey"];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                 completionHandler:
  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@, error: %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], error);
    ;

}] resume];
```

Below are screenshots from Charles Proxy.  There is no response after the connect request.

[image: Request]

Comment: in case you work on Windows platform, have youd tried using Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler ) to grab the HTTP traffic? I haven't seen a web traffic that cannot be handled with Fiddler.

Comment: What do you use to make the request on your iOS app? Can you access the JSON response within your code?

Comment: @Moxy - We use `NSURLConnection` with the `AFNetworking` wrapper.  We can see the request and response in code when Charles is not running.  When Charles is running the connection fails with a SSL error.

Comment: @astaykov - I believe Fiddler captures packets which will not do for SSL data.  We need to effectively do a man-in-the-middle attack to capture data from a SSL connection.  This is what Charles does with a self-signed certificate.  However, it does not work for this SSL connection and I don't know why.

Comment: I think I have the solution to your problem but I would need you to post the code of where you make the network request and what object makes it in order to be as precise as possible. So please post that part of your code!

Comment: @Moxy - Posted code.

Comment: @Robert, you are right, Fiddler does a packet capturing, and there are absolutely no issues with it when everything runs in the same box. Fiddler would have been useless if couldn't decrypt HTTPS traffic...

Answer (score 0):

In order to intercept the request and return a fake response, you could use [`OHHTTPStubs`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs)

To be enable to do it, you should either log the response when debugging from Xcode or use the documentation.

Before you execute your test, call

```
stub = [OHHTTPStubs stubRequestsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSURLRequest *request) {
             return [request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"https://MyDomain.azure-api.net/a/b/2?subscription-key=myKey"];
         }
                           withStubResponse:^OHHTTPStubsResponse *(NSURLRequest *request) {
                                           NSString *fixture = OHPathForFileInBundle(@"fakeResponse.json", nil);
                                           return [OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithFileAtPath:fixture
                                                                                   statusCode:200
                                                                                      headers:@{@"Content-Type":@"text/json"}];
                                       }];
```

And after you execute your test you should call

```
[OHHTTPStubs removeStub:stub];
```

"fakeResponse.json" must be a file **added only to your test target** and you can have different tests with different `JSON` files. For example you can pass a `JSON` with an error or empty content to test if your application behaves the way you want it to behave.